# How to work with external classes in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, google-analytics

To add new functions in wordpress I know we have to do something like this:

```
function favicon() {
    // function code
}
add_action('wp_head', 'favicon');
```

I found in github an interesting project, which parses the cookies of Google Analyitics and with that I can access some information about visitor access: origin, media, sessions, etc.

[Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP](https://github.com/jamesflight/Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP)

But my question as I transform the project classes into wordpress function?

I understand that this may be a broad question but maybe the answer might be short. For example insert a php url include from the file where the class is in functions.php

thanks

**EDIT**

Files created by composer, **function.php** is also at the root of the theme

**------------------**

```
  /THEME
      /vendor
        autoload.php
        /composer
          files of composer
        /jflight
           /gacookie
              /src
              /tests
              other files
  composer.json
  composer.lock
  function.php
```

function.php

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

function get_data_cookies(){

            use Jflight\GACookie\GACookie;

            //utma

            $utma->time_of_first_visit; // DateTime
            $utma->time_of_last_visit; // DateTime
            $utma->time_of_current_visit; // DateTime
            $utma->session_count // Integer

            // utmz

            $utmz->timestamp; // DateTime
            $utmz->session_count // Integer
            $utmz->campaign_number // Integer
            $utmz->source // string
            $utmz->medium // string
            $utmz->campaign // string
            $utmz->term // string
            $utmz->content // string

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_cookies' );
```

How do I call the class correctly?

```
use Jflight\GACookie\GACookie;

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in.. directory theme...functions.php on line 622
```

the `get_data_cookie`s function is correct?

to print anywhere on the theme I simply use:

```
echo $utmz->source;
```

or should I somehow mention the function?

**------- UPDATE------**

```
require get_template_directory().'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Jflight\GACookie\GACookie;


function get_cookies(){

    $utma = GACookie::parse('utma');
    $utmz = GACookie::parse('utmz');
    var_dump( $utma );
    var_dump( $utmz ); 

                    //utma

             $args = $utma->time_of_first_visit; // DateTime
             $args = $utma->time_of_last_visit; // DateTime
             $args = $utma->time_of_current_visit; // DateTime
             $args = $utma->session_count; // Integer

            // utmz

             $args = $utmz->timestamp; // DateTime
             $args = $utmz->session_count; // Integer
             $args = $utmz->campaign_number; // Integer
             $args = $utmz->source; // string
             $args = $utmz->medium; // string
             $args = $utmz->campaign; // string
             $args = $utmz->term; // string
             $args = $utmz->content;  // string


}
```

and in the form of contacts of the theme I am putting

```
<?php get_cookies() ?>
```

but it is returning:

```
bool(false)bool(false)
```

Comment: well, i could answer that and will if you really need it but i strongly advise using a plugin, not incorporating to a theme. It will be much more useful for the wordpress community that way. if you need pointers on plugin development, edit the question and it will be my pleasure to guide you through it. (heck i might just go ahead and make one.. never saw that cookie parser.. ill see what you can get from it that is not already available from the G A plugin...)

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper Thanks I really need to know how it works by implementing within the theme. On the plugin I agree that it will be useful for the wordpress community and I have rather interest in knowing how to develop the plugin

Comment: ok! so ive read the parser doc, and had a bit of fun with it. follow fajwrks lead to bundle up the project and include it in your theme. Then let me know what specifically you would like to DO (what data you want stored, where do you want to store it, and what you want to do with it)

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper I also found the project interesting, I updated my question please see

Comment: apart from you add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_cookies' ); not pointing to your function, you should include from a wordpress function.php file with this : "require(get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/autoload.php');". also, your function does not need to randomly access stuff like that. simply parse the cookie. then those objects will be available from your templates $utma = GACookie::parse('utma');
$utmz = GACookie::parse('utmz');

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper I added details to my question `var_dump` is returning `bool(false)bool(false)`

Comment: ok sorry i was on a long weekend. SO, stupid question, your site IS using google analytics right? its installed and running?

Comment: also, you can use the init hook to call get_cookies

Answer (score 2):

The standard for PHP applications, whether they be WordPress plugins or not, is that you use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to satisfy dependencies and take of advantage of the autoloading that Composer offers.

Notice that the project [Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP](https://github.com/jamesflight/Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP/blob/master/composer.json) has a `composer.json` file in the GitHub repo? You can take full advantage of that. Also notice (by reviewing its `composer.json` file) that the name of the package is `"name": "jflight/gacookie"`. So the name is `jflight/gacookie`.

Therefore, if your goal is to utilize functionality offered by this class, here are a suggested list of next actions that will get you where you need to be:

- Review: https://getcomposer.org/
- Install Composer on your personal computer.

With Composer installed, from a terminal (command-line) type:

```
$ cd /path/to/local/project/dir
$ composer require jflight/gacookie
```

That automatically downloads the class files and puts them all into a special folder in your project directory named `vendor/`. It will also create a `composer.json` file in your project directory.

Now you can take advantage of a Composer feature called autoloading. To utilize the new dependency that you just required at the command line, add the following line into your PHP file, which is where you began when asking this question.

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

function favicon() {
    // Refer to the class documentation.
    // You can now use the class here to achieve something.
}
add_action('wp_head', 'favicon');
```

**Tip:** It's worth noting that any additional dependencies that you add by typing `composer require something/else` from the command-line, will automatically become available as well, because the `vendor/autoload.php` file will automatically load them when/if code in your own PHP files attempts to use a PHP class that would otherwise be missing. That's why it's called an 'auto' loader.

---

**WordPress:** When you install this into WordPress, you should upload everything, including the entire `vendor/` directory and its contents. Those are now your plugin's dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your help was very enlightening, I followed your guidance and I studied about the composer and now I updated my question please see